# Mail program not showing all Exchange Sent boxes

Tags: mail.app, email, exchange

I'm using Mail (version 5.3) on Mac OS X version 10.7.5. I have three different e-mail accounts which all are Exchange accounts by their type. All of them work correctly, I can send and receive e-mails. Problem is that in Mail program under "Sent" only the sent box of the latest account created is showing (see attached picture below). Of course, I would like to have all sent boxes from all accounts to be visible under "Sent".

Wondering, if someone here has bumped into same problem because I couldn't find any helpful answer from Apple's forums or anywhere else. Hovewer, it seems that I'm not alone with this problem. Could the problem be in Mail itself or in misconfigured Exchange Server or..?

[image: e-mail accounts]

Comment: I have a stupid question: I assume when you send you choose different account in send from ?

Comment: Yes, and I mostly use Exchange 1 account for sending e-mails. Other two Exchange accounts are mostly for receiving e-mails.

Comment: So there is nothing in the other 2 send folders?

Comment: There are few sent e-mails in Exchange accounts 2 and 3 and several in account 1.

Comment: You should see all 3 accounts (separate) under the smart folders, each having the send email folder!

Comment: Yep :) and would be nice to know why sent boxes of all accounts are not showing.

Comment: OK, let me try to replicate your problem......